# I have a search bar, after searching item in search bar, if I click back button the app closes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a search bar, after searching in the search bar, if I click back button the app closes. What I want is if I click back button after searching in search bar the default list must be shown.

```
   activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if(){

            }else{
                isEnabled = false
                activity?.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    })

searchBar.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                val listData = arrayListOf<Restaurant>()
                for (i in 0 until restaurantInfoList.size) {
                    if (restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantName.toLowerCase()
                            .contains(searchBar.text.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
                        restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantPrice.contains(searchBar.text.toString()) ||
                        restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantRating.contains(searchBar.text.toString())
                    ) {
                        listData.add(restaurantInfoList[i])
                    }
                }
                recyclerDashboard.adapter = RestaurantRecycleAdapter(activity as Context, listData)
                (recyclerDashboard.adapter as RestaurantRecycleAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            
        }
        )
```

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` in activity, and perform appropriate operation by checking if search is applied or not. You may, also, want to learn about `onBackPressedDispatcher`

Comment: Sure, add a callback to `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(...)`.

Comment: I have edited the program, the condition is when Im in search bar and click back button  default list should be shown. How to mention the condition

Comment: Check the search bar has focus or not.

Comment: From above code, If `searchBar` has any text, content is filtered. If search box is empty, content is whole/original.

Comment: Yes, but if I search something and click back the app closes.

Answer (score 0):

The app is closing because you have called the activity's onbackPressed() method. Unless you handle the callback on your own, it will close.
In your backpressed method, check if your search bar is empty and produce the default list in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in else condition

```
 activity?.onBackPressed()
```

Comment: Still the list collapses